HP ESP120 Server PSU: What is this part for?
I have an HP ESP120 Power Supply that I am using for my RC battery charger (Yes, big batteries). Since the case is quite bulky I am in the process of building a new case.
I noticed a little separate PCB which is connected to the inside of the casing, held in by a screw an a metal pin, the latter not seeming to be connected in any way. Is the pin just for heat transfer? Since it says "THR1" next to the little red component: Is that a thermistor and if yes, what does it do? Check for case overheating?




THR1 and the size and shape tells me it's a temperature sensor.
Test with a multimeter in resistance mode. I would suspect it's 10 kΩ NTC.
As for use, it's harder to tell. For critical cut-off, they tend to be placed on hot-spots such as transformers or semiconductor heatsinks, but perhaps measuring just ambient was fine for this application? If it really is a 10 kΩ NTC and you really want to find out, replace with a 10 kΩ potentiometer and turn it down and see if the unit shuts of at some point, just raise the fan speeds or a combination.

Server grade gear often measures both heatsink temperature and intake air temperature - sometimes discharge temp, too. Given the construction this is definitely measuring air temp not part temp.

Thank you both very much. It's located right behind the fans so your answers make perfect sense. I'll just leave it where it is. The PSU will now get a silent large fan as compared to the deafening small OEM fans.

If it's behind the fans, is there one in front too?

No it's the only one. The fans are at the very end of the case.

And just for completeness, the pin is there for locating purposes -- it keeps the board from spinning when you tighten the screw.
